# Stray points plotted when using HighlightGraph to visualize DegreeCentrality

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

When I use `HighlightGraph` to visualize the directed edges of a digraph and its `DegreeCentrality`, stray points are plotted which do not appear to be part of the original directed edge dataset.

Here is an MWE with Presidential Inaugural addresses:

```
inaugural = 
  SortBy[ResourceData["Presidential Inaugural Addresses"], "Date"];
washington = inaugural[[1]]["Text"];
washingtonwords = 
  WordStem@TextWords@ToLowerCase@DeleteStopwords@washington;
washingtonDE = 
 DirectedEdge @@@ 
  Partition[washingtonwords, 2, 1];(*directed edges*)dcWashington = 
 DegreeCentrality[Graph[washingtonDE]];
gWashington = Graph[washingtonDE];
HighlightGraph[gWashington, VertexList[gWashington], 
 VertexSize -> 
  Thread[VertexList[gWashington] -> Rescale[dcWashington]]]
```

The outcome of `HighlightGraph` is below and it shows these stray dots all over the place.  These dots **disappear** when I size the graph with my mouse (see this [**GIF**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXVPW.jpg)).

[image]

*Version and OS information*: I am using Mathematica 13.0.0.0 for Linux x86 64.

**Is this a Linux/Mathematica issue or an error in how I am doing this?**

Comment: "washingtonwords" is not defined

Comment: @DanielHuber fixed.

Comment: I don't see the red dots on upper left corner in the GIF file you have linked. I am using v12.2.0 on Win7-x64. I also tested your code on the free cloud account `running 13.0.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (January 29, 2022)` and these dots are not visible there either.

Comment: Windows 10 version 13.0.1  I only see red dots and small lines at the vertices, but no superfluous points.

Comment: @DanielHuber I wonder if this is a graphics card issue.  I'll check with Wolfram support.